# Passing object of string arrays in nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, soapui, soap-client, nusoap

I have developed a `PHP` web service with `nusoap`. There is a function which get an object of string arrays. The object contains some elements such as number and every element is an array of strings. Following code works in php clinet file:

**Define Complex type**

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(   
'ArrayReq',    
'complexType',    
'struct',    
'all',    
'',    
array(    
'number' => array('name' => 'number', 'type' => 'tns:dataArray')    
));

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(    
  'dataArray',    
  'complexType',    
  'array',    
  '',    
  'SOAP-ENC:Array',    
  array(),    
  array(    
    array(    
      'ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',    
      'wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')    
    )    
  );


//Register Method     

$server->register('GetTotal',    
array('number' => 'tns:ArrayReq'),// and this line also.     
array('return' => 'tns:ArrayReq'),    
'urn:GetArr',    
'urn:GetArr#GetTotalPrice',    
'rpc',    
'encoded',    
'Get total'    
);
```

But in **SoapUI the request** is the same as below :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:GetArr" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">    
   <soapenv:Header/>    
   <soapenv:Body>    
      <urn:GetTotalPrice soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">    
         <number xsi:type="urn:ArrayReq" xmlns:urn="urn:tpswsdl">    
            <number xsi:type="urn:dataArray" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>    
         </number>    
      </urn:GetTotalPrice>    
   </soapenv:Body>
```

How can i change it to send request with soapUI?

Comment: What is the expected request look like after populating with the data from array? and How the data is coming into array?Using a file such as csv, txt or something else?